# Algorithm to assign edge values for a jigsaw puzzle pieces that gurantees uniqueness, but allow up to 3 sides to be the same?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to write a little program (I am using C++, but any language would do) as an exercise that would create a 4x4 jigsaw puzzle. The puzzle has 16 pieces each with 4 edges, thus 48 inner edges (16 being outer flat edges). Each edge is represented by an integer value (say an integer between 1 and 48, with 0 means flat). Two edges that adds up to 49 is considered a fit. My original thought was to walk from the top left corner and assign values sequentially starting from 1, then assign 49-x to the opposite edge. While this would work, I realized that each edge would be unique, which is not how jigsaw puzzles in real life is. A better way would be for pieces to have up to 3 edges being the same with another piece, thus making solving it a lot harder. I thought about doing this by randomly assigning an integer between 1 and 48 instead of doing it in sequence. However, I also would like to make the solution unique. Thus two pieces cannot have the same 4 edges in any orientation. Any ideas how I should do that other than brutal force searching each time to guarantee uniqueness? Thx.

Comment: Jigsaw puzzles I've used DO have unique edges!  
Nice solution to sum to 49!
What do you mean by "3 edges being the same with another piece"?  
"Normal" puzzles have edges with either "something" sticking out or cut into - is that what you mean? - Anyway, a "good" puzzle has one, and only one - solution (in my opinion).

Comment: @iAmOren If all the edges are unique (i.e. no two pieces have any of their 4 edges the same), then to find a piece on the right of a piece that has right edge value of x, we just need to find a piece with the left edge value of 49-x. We do not have to worry about what's above the new pieces and below the new piece since we know there's only a single piece with left edge value of 49-x. That's not how jigsaw puzzle works normally.

Comment: Instead, I would like to have many pieces with the right edge value of x, thus many pieces with left edge value of 49-x, but only one such pieces would fit there to fit with other pieces. In the most extreme cases, we can have many pieces with 3 edges being the same, but one edge being different. However, we shouldn't have two pieces that are interchangeable (i.e. all 4 edges are the same in certain orientation, e.g. {1,2,3,4} and {2,3,4,1})

Comment: Now that I think of it, it might be better to assign unique numbers up front and then randomly making the meaning of some of the numbers the same. For example, 1 and 11 could represent the same edge. That way, the difficulty of the jigsaw puzzle can be increased by creating similar pieces in a controlled way. However, interchangeable pieces would still be a problem. :(

Comment: To keep the pieces unique, assign an ID to each piece as follows. Create the array of edge numbers. Then rotate the array so the smallest number is first. Then encode the base 64. For example, if the edges are [a,b,c,d], then the ID is `((a*64+b)*64+c)*64+d`. Then keep a set of the used IDs so that you can easily check for duplicates.

Comment: @user3386109 Thx. Yeah, I thought of rotating the array to have a fixed order, although I didn't think of base64 encoding it. That's a good idea. I can then put them into a BST to do fast search. I guess there's no way to avoid the search? If I do find a collision, which should be very rare, I guess I can just use an unused edge value to avoid further collision, which lowers the difficulty of the puzzle a bit, but not much.

Comment: I was thinking hash table, but a BST works too. Some programming languages have a built-in `set` type that hides the details, so you don't have to think about it.